# Can I create a canvas with multiple moving objects and still be able to provide actions?

Tags: python

Let´s say I want to create a game in Python, where a lot of cars will move in canvas, and I still (while they are moving) want to be able to make some actions, like buying items from a shop and so on. Is this possible to do in Python, without any game library import?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, but it's not recommended.

Long answer:

For the first part of your question is doable. You can use the `tkinter` module to create multiple moving objects on your canvas. This is done by using an object oriented program which makes different classes for your cars, in this scenario, and sets them to move. If you want a link for that, [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710067/generating-multiple-moving-objects-in-the-tkinter-canvas). Adding functionality can be a bit annoying, but again, it's `tkinter`. However, putting these together? It sucks. Based on a lot of articles I've read, making a game in `tkinter`, is, to put it simply, a very long and painful experience. I **highly** recommend you to use a game library such as `pygame` or `pyglet`, but you technically still can do it in `tkinter`. So, in conclusion: don't make a game in `tkinter`, but you still technically can.